# Dragging a div a fixed distance from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I am creating a project where I want to be able to drag a div (a drawer) that is (mostly) positioned off the bottom of the screen a fixed distance on the Y axis. The distance I want to move is the height of the div (drawer - minus the drawer handle).

It was pretty easy to get this working from top to bottom, but reversing it is posing to be quite a challenge. I feel like it might just be a simple math error.

I have put together a fiddle to better illustrate the issues I'm having.

http://jsfiddle.net/q8DE6/2/

Here's my code:
**HTML**

```
 <div id="panelWrapper">
  <div id="panel" class="panel">
    <p> The height of this drawer is dynamic, and will slide the appropriate amounted based on the height of the content. </p>
    <p> Any type of content can be included in here. The body of the drawer and the drawer pull tab can also be styled as you see fit, just modify the css/styles.css file. </p>

    <!--necessary div for slide tab, modify as needed, but don't delete -->
    <div class="slide">
        <a id="drawerSlide" href="#" class="drawer-slide">
            <table id="sTab" class="slideTab">
              <tr>
                  <td id="stText1"></td>
                  <td id="stImg">Pull here.</td>
                  <td id="stText2"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a> 
     </div>
  </div><!--/panel --> 
</div><!--/panelWrapper --> 


<div id="content">
<div id="header">
    <div id="menuBar">
        <h3>Header Bar Text.</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer Area.</p>
</div>

</div><!--/content -->
```

Slide Function:
**JS:**

```
function drawerSlide(slideDir) {
switch (slideDir) {
    case 'bottomToTop':
            //drawer styling
            $('.panel, .slide').addClass('botToTop');
            $('.panel').addClass('panelTB');
            $('.slide').addClass('slideBotToTop');
            $('#sTab').addClass('slideTab');
            $('.panel p').filter(":first").css('padding-top','50px');

            //hide overflown Y axis content. Hopefully this won't cause any conflicts with your existing code/page.
            $('body').css('overflow-y','hidden');

            botStartPos = $(window).height() - 50;
            offset = $('#panel').offset();

            panelHeight = $('#panel').outerHeight();
            topEndPos = botStartPos - panelHeight +50;
            yPos = botStartPos;

            // if you need a different drawer starting point, adjust the starting position here (50).
            panelHeight = parseFloat(panelHeight) - 50;


            console.log("botStartPos:" + botStartPos);
            console.log("topEndPos:" + topEndPos);
            console.log("yPos:" + yPos);

            $('.panel').css('top', botStartPos);

            $('#panel').draggable({
                    axis: "y",
                    containment: [0, botStartPos, 0, topEndPos] //0, botStartPos, 300, topEndPos 
                }, 
                {
                drag: function( event, ui ) {
                    if  (yPos > botStartPos || yPos < topEndPos) {
                        return false;
                    } 
                    else {
                        offset = $(this).offset();
                        yPos = offset.top;
                        console.log(yPos);
                    }
                }  
            }); 
}
}


$(document).ready(function() {
        drawerSlide("bottomToTop");
    });
```

I'm thinking the issue might be with the way I'm using the offset.top command to move the drawer, but I'm stumped as to how to do it correctly.

Right now what is happening, is when you click/hold the handle, it "jumps" up the fixed distance, instead of being able to drag it. Also, you can't drag down to put the drawer away, but you can drag up once again and it "jumps" down the fixed distance. Not really what I'm after.

The desired result I'm looking for is one of a typical "drawer" behavior. When the user clicks and holds on the handle, they can "pull" the drawer up the fixed distance, and then "push" it back down the same fixed distance, so the handle never falls off screen.

My guess is it that it's a math problem with the containment function. I still don't fully understand it well, so the problem may lie within the coordinates I'm using?

Any advice would be most appreciated. :)

Comment: Have spent more time messing with the coordinate system of draggable, and I'm still lost. If anyone could take a peek at the fiddle and give me a nudge in the right direction, I'd be so ever grateful.

Comment: Does any kind soul out there have a suggestion for me? I still can't figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: After months of trying to wrap my head around this concept, I still can't get it.

Does anyone have a suggestion? It must be something simple, that I'm just not seeing.